# PHP - replacing strings in PDF file

Tags: php, pdf

i am looking for something to edit my PDF files on my server and replace text / links within.

I can not modify the files as they are generated, therefore i need a script that will modify them after.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

http://www.fpdf.org/

http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/

You need to read the pdf file first and then change the text and Regenerate it again

Comment: You cannot [edit](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-i-edit-a-pdf-document-with-fpdi/#question-82) or change the imported page content with FPDI!